# One-liner to convert two newlines to one?

Tags: unix, newline

I have a file where I want to convert "\n" to " " and "\n\n" to "\n".
For example:

```
I
had
a
toy
.

It
was
good
.
```

Becomes:

```
I had a toy .
It was good .
```

Does anyone have a Unix one-liner for this operation?

Comment: Your example does not reflect your rules.  If "\n" becomes " ", then there would be no newlines left AT ALL.

Comment: I think his example makes the question clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fmt | sed '/^$/d'
```

The fmt command will wrap lines at 75 characters, so use fmt -w [WIDTH] to set longer lines.

Comment: Do you even need the sed command here?  I thought fmt would handle this on its own.

Comment: acrosman, I tried w/o using sed.  I couldn't find an option to fmt that would remove the blank line.

Answer (score 3):

if you have gawk

```
# awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{$1=$1}1'  file
I had a toy .
It was good .
```

Comment: +1 nice! This doesn't have the line length limit that my answer has.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another Awk solution:

```
$ cat data.txt 
I
had
a
toy
.

It
was
good
.

$ awk '{printf "%s ", $0} /^$/{print ""}' data.txt 
I had a toy .  
It was good .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had installed Ruby ,this is the one-liner that do the trick.

```
irb(main):014:0> puts f.gsub(/[a-zA-Z.](\n)/) {|s| s.chomp +" "}
I had a toy . 
It was good .
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [bmb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5298/bmb)'s comment to his/her own answer hinted at the difficulty you may have had if you 'googled' for suggestions.

Google 'remove blank lines'.

Maybe fmt won't do it by itself, but there are many methods.

I liked the `grep` approach

```
grep -v "^$" filename > newfilename
```

although it's a little messy to have to rename the file.

EDIT: one of the hits found by 'remove blank lines Perl' gave

```
perl -pi -e "s/^\n//" file.txt
```

Comment: grep doesn't have the ability to "modify" content.

Comment: but it's not modifying content - it's just filtering out blank lines and sending them to a different file.

Comment: oops, I mean grep is sending *everything but* the blank lines to a different file. Grep is a **filter**, and pretty useful at that.

Comment: You could avoid renaming by using sponge from the moreutils package. 
grep -v "^$" filename | sponge filename

Comment: I would probably avoid renaming the file, and avoid a pipeline, by invoking perl in 'edit in place' mode.

Comment: Neither of these solutions converts "\n" to " "

Comment: True, that requirement has been overlooked. I must look at the documentation for fmt. I don't have it in Cygwin.

Comment: Hmm ... **!}fmt** has promise as a means of formatting paragraphs in vim.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can think of is this:

```
tr '\n' '#' | sed 's/##/\n/g' | sed 's/#//g'
```

Where # is some character not used in the file, that's the downside of it. You'll have to use some unique character ;)